# Conexión Cliente-Servidor entre Windows y Raspberry C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

tengo un problema que no se bien como atajar, he estado probando cosas y nada me ha funcionado por ahora.

Tengo un programa desarrollado en Visual Studio con C#, el cual funciona de Servidor, el objetivo de este programa es enviarle datos al cliente para que este los muestre en pantalla, el codigo para conectar con el cliente es el siguiente:

```
    TcpClient socket;
    NetworkStream stream;
    StreamReader input;
    StreamWriter output;
    private int puerto1 = 11000, puerto2 = 11000;
    private string svIP = "127.0.0.1";

public bool Conectar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Conectando display...");
        conectando = true;
        string serial;
        //Always call UpdateDeviceList() before using AndroidController on devices to get the most updated list
        //android.UpdateDeviceList();
        //if (android.ConnectedDevices.Count > 0)
        //{
        //try
        /*{
            serial = android.ConnectedDevices[0];
            device = android.GetConnectedDevice(serial);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conectando = false;
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Estadistica.registrarError(this.serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
            conectado = false;
            conectada(conectado);
            return false;
        }
        if (android.HasConnectedDevices)
        {*/
        AdbCommand adbCmd = Adb.FormAdbCommand("forward", "tcp:" + puerto1 + " tcp:" + puerto2);
        int resultado = Adb.ExecuteAdbCommandReturnExitCode(adbCmd);
        //if (resultado == 0)
        //{
        try
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Close();
                stream.Close();
                //input.Close();
                //output.Close();
            }
            socket = new TcpClient(svIP, puerto1);
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                stream = socket.GetStream();
                //stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                input = new StreamReader(stream);
                output = new StreamWriter(stream);
                output.AutoFlush = true;
                conectado = true;
                conectada(conectado);
                //output.WriteLine("OK");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Tablet conectar() socket no conectado");
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            conectando = false;
            Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente SocketException");
            //Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            conectado = false;
            conectada(conectado);
            //Desconectar();
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            conectando = false;
            Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente FormatException");
            //Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            conectado = false;
            conectada(conectado);
            //Desconectar();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            conectando = false;
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        //}
        //}
        //}
        conectando = false;
        return conectado;
    }
```

Se compone de un socket como podeis ver con un input y un output, para enviar datos a el cliente uso el siguiente método:

```
 public void enviarTexto(string linea1, string linea2)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("enviarTexto()");
        if (socket != null && socket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                //output.Write(linea1);
                output.Flush();
                String result = linea2 + "\n";
                String result2 = linea1 + "\n";
                output.Flush();
                //output.Write(result2);
                output.Flush();
                output.Write(result);
                output.Flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TabletCliente IOException " + e.Message);
                Estadistica.registrarError(serial, Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.SOFTWARE, e.StackTrace);
                //Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                socket.Close();
                input.Close();
                output.Close();
                conectado = false;
                conectada(conectado);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                if (socket != null)
                    stream = socket.GetStream();
                if (stream != null)
                    input = new StreamReader(stream);
                if (stream != null)
                    output = new StreamWriter(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Por ahora todo bien, tengo otro programa desarrollado en Visual Studio con c# que funciona de cliente para recibir datos, el codigo de la clase que funciona como cliente es el siguiente:

```
     public class StateObject
     {
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Array
    public ArrayList listaValores = new ArrayList();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static String dinero;
    static ArrayList ListaV = new ArrayList();


    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {

    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        //Cambiar para que haga rastreo?
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Aceptado");
        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;


        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            //Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();

            //Console.WriteLine(content);
            ListaV.Add(content);

            for (int i = 0; i < ListaV.Count; i++) {
                //Console.WriteLine("Dentro de la lista "+ListaV[i]);
            }
            string s = (string)ListaV[ListaV.Count - 1];
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            if (ListaV.Count >= 2) {
                Form1 obj = new Form1();
                obj.Show();
                obj.llamarArray(ListaV);
                obj.Show();
                ListaV.Clear();
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(content+ "Uno");
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the   
                // client. Display it on the console.
                //Console.WriteLine(content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                //Insertar y obtener  la cantidad

                //Send(handler, content);  
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Intento de callback
    public static string getTotal()
    {
        return dinero;
    }

    public static void setTotal(string total)
    {
        dinero = total;
        //Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Insert(1,dinero);
    }
}
```

Como veis es asincrono y recibe datos constantemente, estos datos los llevo al form para mostrarlos y funciona todo perfectamente.

El problema viene cuando paso mi programa a la raspberry y lo ejecuto con el comando:

```
$ mono Display.exe
```

Este comando me abre en linux el programa que funciona como cliente pero este no llega a conectar con el servidor nunca, los 2 estan en la IP de localhost por lo que no deberia haber ningun problema,

Alguno se le ocurre que puede estar pasando?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione cambiando la ip de localhost.